# Deepsecurity API call for Even-Based Tasks

Tags: automation, deepsecurity

Need help as i am unable to locate API (https://automation.deepsecurity.trendmicro.com/article/12_0/api-reference?platform=on-premise) for creating Event-Based Tasks.

I want to create create a task when a VM from specific platform join my DSM,attach a policy to it. (e.g., if the platform is RHEL, assign my RHEL policy and for windows, assign Windows policy).

Please point me to the documentation for the Event-based Tasks API.

Thank you so much.

Regards
CH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Deep Security as a Service, or Deep Security Feature Release since late October 2019, then Event-Based Tasks are available in the new /api, with docs: https://automation.deepsecurity.trendmicro.com/article/fr/api-reference?platform=on-premise#tag/Event-Based-Tasks

If you are using an earlier version of Deep Security, such as Deep Security 12, then Event-Based Tasks are available in the Legacy /rest api, with docs: https://automation.deepsecurity.trendmicro.com/legacy-rest/12_0/index.html?env=onprem#event_based_tasks

As a member of the Deep Security R&D team, I hope that answers your question.